# AES decryption Android

Tags: java, c#, android, encryption, cryptography

I am working on AES encryption and decryption in Android, I post request using below Android code snippet.

**Request Post**

```
   String urlParameters = "username=abc&password=abc";
            String request = "http://abcd.co.uk/data_abc.php?";
            String passkey = "mysecretkey";

   URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        //Create connection
        url = new URL(request);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +
                Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        //Get Response
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } finally {

        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

And I successfully got Base64 Encrypted response string from the above request but when I try to decrypt the response string using following code snippet, It return unreadable string like characters and boxes.

**Decryption**

```
  String strDecriptedValue = decrypt(passkey, responseBase64);

public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted)
            throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] enc = Base64.decode(encrypted.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
        return new String(result);
    }

private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        random.setSeed(seed);
        keygen.init(128, random); 
        SecretKey key = keygen.generateKey();
        byte[] raw = key.getEncoded();
        return raw;
    }

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted)
            throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }
```

**Decrypted Output**

��]ة*�]��O��Z���Q2�_

The response should be in JSON format but actual output is like above.

Please share the snippet which is used to decrypt the data with AES 256 bit, secure key using Base 64.

And also I tried using AES/CBC/NoPadding , AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding etc., but its not getting work.

Comment: are you using `Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files` ?

Comment: No, I am using AES256 decryption

Comment: for using 256 bit encryption you should have `Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, It would be most appreciable if you share the       tutorial / code snippet or any other reference to achieve AES256 decryption in android.

Answer (score 0):

You are using SecureRandom random to generated key using passed seed value.
But the actual implementation of SecureRandom on the server and the one used by your Android code be different (you are using some PHP code it seems) so the generated key value would be different.

Also you mentioned the 256 bit key but your code is using 128 instead: `keygen.init(128, random);`

So make sure that your are using the same keys on both side. You should try your code first with the 'fixed' key on both side and check if it works, otherwise you may still have bugs in your decryption/encryption process. You included only half of the process code in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as you said my code snippet was made for 128 bit. so I tried using 256 bit but its not working. still I am searching for proper AES 256 decryption code. can you please share the proper code snippet for AES 256 bit.

Comment: keygen.init(256, random); Are you getting exception or does your decoded value is not correct?

Comment: Not getting any exceptions, and my decoded value is like this([-83, -7, 42, -51, -87, 76, -70, -71, -25, etc.,). Is correctly decoded or wrong.